# Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, passenger

I have a problem with Rails 4.1.7, Phusion Passenger version 4.0.53, nginx/1.6.2 in ubuntu server 14.04 AWS Instance, but With rails server works well.

error.log

> App 2029 stdout:  App 2029 stderr: sh: 1:  App 2029 stderr: env: not
>   found App 2029 stderr:  App 2029 stdout:  [ 2014-11-12 16:12:26.1580
>   1979/7feff83f9700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:287 ]: Could not spawn
>   process for application /home/ubuntu/apps/doger: An error occured
>   while starting up the preloader.   Error ID: b7381860   Error details
>   saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-SUjzpL.html   Message from application:
>   Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See
>   https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available
>   runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)
>   /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-2.2.2/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:51:in
>   `autodetect'
>
>   /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-2.2.2/lib/execjs.rb:5:in`
>   '
>   /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-2.2.2/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top
>   (required)>'
>
>   /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/uglifier-2.5.3/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in`require'
>   /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/uglifier-2.5.3/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in `<top
>   (required)>'
>
>   /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in`
>   require'
>   /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in
>   `block (2 levels) in require'
>
>   /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in`
>   each'
>   /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in
>   `block in require'
>
>   /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in`
>   each'
>   /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in
>   `require'
>
>   /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler.rb:133:in`require'
>   /home/ubuntu/apps/doger/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>' 
>   /home/ubuntu/apps/doger/config/environment.rb:2:in`require'
>   /home/ubuntu/apps/doger/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>' 
>   config.ru:3:in`require'   config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
>
>   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/builder.rb:55:in`instance_eval'
>   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
>
>   config.ru:1:in`new'   config.ru:1:in `<main>'
>
>   /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:112:in`eval'
>   /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:112:in
>   `preload_app'
>
>   /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:158:in`
>   '
>   /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in
>   `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
>
>   /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in`'
>
> [ 2014-11-12 16:12:26.1691 1979/7feff60bf700
>   agents/HelperAgent/RequestHandler.h:2306 ]: [Client 20] Cannot
>   checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of
>   the error is b7381860. Please see earlier logs for details about the
>   error.

GemFile

```
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.7'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
#gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development
```

I have already installed nodejs (v0.10.25)

Answer (score 17):

I get this problem every time I setup a new ubuntu/nginx/passenger/rails server. Try this

First install node:

`sudo apt-get install nodejs`

then add your path env to your /etc/nginx/nginx.conf like so:

`env PATH;`

or to be more specific (if node is located at /usr/bin/nodejs):

`env PATH=/bin:/usr/bin;`

Comment: Is there a more specific way instead of exposing the whole PATH to nginx ?

Answer (score 4):

Uncomment line with 'therubyracer' gem, like this:

```
gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby
```

and run bundle install. I hope this will help you.

Comment: The OP is supposed to use nodejs installed system wide, not therubyracer

Answer (score 0):

I had run into a similar problem and I had nodejs already running on my machine. It was after all the looking had I came to realize I need to include execjs gem in my Gemfile:

```
gem "execjs", "~> 2.8.1"
```

And run `bundle install`